# Search and clean Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to schedule a search of my email and remove those emails. I've got this:

```
function cleanMail(){
  var search = GmailApp.search('from:(abc@mail.com) to:(####@sms.net) subject:subject)');
  var thread = search.getThreads();
  thread.moveToTrash();
}
```

I am getting

> TypeError: Cannot find function getThreads in object GmailThread,GmailThread,GmailThread,GmailThread,GmailThread.'

Comment: I'm not sure what you expected - the return value of [`GmailApp#search`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)) is **already** an array of [`GmailThread`s](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function cleanMail(){
  var threads = GmailApp.search('from:"abc@mail.com" to:"####@sms.net" subject:"subject"');
  for(var i=0;i<threads.length;i++) {
    threads[i].moveToTrash();
  }
}
```